# How can I rewrite an URL with a page number with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website and trying to rewrite it’s url. The pages are as:

```
www.mydomain.com/newv2/pvgs.php?archive=april/2014
www.mydomain.com/newv2/pvgs.php?archive=april/2014&page=1
```

I have using pagination but I want when any one click on for archive months then he will get only 1 URL as `http://www.mydomain.com/newv2/april/2014`

And when he click on pagination the page nuber added at last means 2nd url 
as `http://www.mydomain.com/newv2/april/2014/1`.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in `/newv2/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newv2/

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+/[0-9]+)/?$ pvgs.php?archive=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+/[0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ pvgs.php?archive=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```